# Inserting rows into TargetTable, comparing rows from a select in a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a stored procedure, and it's not working as I would expect. Looking for a fresh set of eyes to see what I am missing. I am populating a table with some distinct values, and if those values don't exist in the table I'm inserting into, then do it. Don't want dupes. The list of values has rows, but it is not inserting into the target table.

```
declare @DistinctTable table (tableName varchar(30))

insert into @DistinctTable (tableName) (SELECT DISTINCT Reference FROM dbo.Tmp_Import_Rows)


INSERT INTO [dbo].[TargetTable] 
       (RowID
       ,A
       ,B
       ,C
       ,D
       ,E
       ,F
       ,G
       ,User
       ,Machine
       ,Date
       ,TableRef)

       (SELECT NEWID(), 
        0,
       0, 
       0, 
       0,
       0, 
       0, 
       0, 
       @pUserName,
       HOST_NAME(), 
       getdate(), 
       tableName
       FROM @DistinctTable 
       WHERE (tableName NOT IN (select [TableRef] from [TargetTable] )))
```

As I said, I'm getting rows into @DistinctTable, but they won't insert into [TargetTable]. I feel like I'm overlooking something small. Any advice would be great, thank you.

---

Edit: Sample data

```
dbo.TargetTable
RowId, TableReferecne| Inches | Volume | Unused | Unused | Unused | Unused | UserName | MACHINE | DATE | Table#

897e0a1f-f139-4c1d-9bac-0a64518cd56a, Table50, 12,20,0,0,0,0,someuser, somemachine, 4-24-15, Table50
```

---

```
dbo.Tmp_Import_Rows

TableReference | Inches| Volume | Table #
Table60        | 60    |  1000  | Table 60
Table70        | 70    |  1100  | Table 70
```

---

@DistinctTable is populated with unique values, On [Table #]

```
tableName

Table60
Table70
```

What I want it to do, is Get Distinct values from Tmp_Import_rows, and if those values don't exist in TargetTable, Insert it.

Comment: what error you getting? and include sample data and expected output

Comment: What is the error message returned by SQL Server?

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not getting any errors. Just (0 row(s) affected)

Comment: @pUserName is a paramater of the stored procedure that gets passed in.

Comment: What does `SELECT * FROM @DistinctTable WHERE TableName NOT IN (SELECT [TableRef] FROM [TargetTable])` return? How many rows are you expecting to be inserted?

Comment: @Michael It returns nothing, even though there are rows in that table that should not match, and be inserted. I'm expecting anywhere between 1 and 1000

Comment: That would definitely be an issue! Can you update the question to include records that should be in the table, but aren't? E.g., records from `Tmp_Import_Rows` that aren't in `TargetTable`? My next suggestion would be to try writing a `MERGE` statement that has the same functionality just to try something different.

Comment: @jamesp:- I am not understand why are you not including Sample and Expected Output? for what you are waiting? we all are just firing in the dark.

Comment: @Piyush You are right, my apologies. I thought it was just a simple error in the where statement. I'll edit with sample data now. Thank you

Comment: @Piyush I added the data

Comment: you are using SELECT DISTINCT Reference FROM dbo.Tmp_Import_Rows but table has only TableReference  column, there is no Reference column in table dbo.Tmp_Import_Rows

Comment: That must be a typo, he does say that DistinctTable is getting populated.

Comment: @jamesp I quickly built a SQL Fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39cdd5/1, and it seems that everything is ok. If something was missed, could you edit the fiddle and add it to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try `WHERE NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` and see if you get anything in return:

```
SELECT *
FROM @DistinctTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [dbo].[TargetTable] t2
        WHERE t1.tableName = t2.tableRef
        );
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to correlate that EXISTS clause to the main query?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need the keyword VALUES in there?

e.g. `insert into table (col1,col2,col3...) values (val1,val2,val3...)` etc?